# Wake phone from unlock screen android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, wakelock

Hеllo guуs, I want to unlock the phone with service. I'm using alarm manager.
Receiver and Service were added to manifest
and also permissions for RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETE and WAKE_LOCK
AlarmReceiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        setAlarms(context);
    }

    public static void setAlarms(Context context) {
        cancelAlarms(context);
        PendingIntent pIntent = createPendingIntent(context);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        setAlarm(context, calendar, pIntent);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private static void setAlarm(Context context, Calendar calendar, PendingIntent pIntent) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
        }
    }

    public static void cancelAlarms(Context context) {
                    PendingIntent pIntent = createPendingIntent(context);
                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarmManager.cancel(pIntent);
    }

    private static PendingIntent createPendingIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        return PendingIntent.getService(context, 777, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
}
```

AlarmService

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {

    public static String TAG = AlarmService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
        alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        alarmIntent.putExtras(intent);
        getApplication().startActivity(alarmIntent);

        //AlarmManagerHelper.setAlarms(this);
        Log.e("SERVICE_WORKING","YEEEES!!!!");

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

}
```

MainActivity

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis()+10000, pendingIntent);
```

It works fine, but if i lock the screen it doesn't unlock it.

Comment: I didn't catch, what do you mean by unlocking phone? You would like to unlock phone even if it has password or pin for unlock – and move from device sleep to device is on a screen with running launcher state? So, in this case this is impossible, I think.

Comment: sorry, i meant unlocking the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are simply looking for MainActivity to show when the phone is locked, there are Window flags that can be set in onCreate() to make that happen.

FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED will enable your activity to be visible to the user when the phone is locked, and FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD will unlock the phone IF the user has not configured a secure (pin/pattern/face/etc) keyguard.

```
    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

Comment: I want to start rington and alert the user like alarm clock

Comment: I used also flags FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON and FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON. It worked, but i saw other people used PowerManager? is it right tto use PowerManager?

Comment: There were many lollipop changes to powermanager & wakelocks. You may want to take a look at AlarmActivity.java (standard android alarm clock) to see how they do it - https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/dfd1960/src/com/android/deskclock/alarms/AlarmActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

You can only cause the screen to awaken via the alarm using a wakelock.  You cannot unlock the screen programmatically.  That would bypass the security the user has selected, which is not allowed.

Also, note that right now you are using a `PendingIntent` with your alarm to start the `Service` which in turn starts the `Activity`.  This is not guaranteed to work when the device is in a low power state.  If you need to wake the device, use a `PendingIntent` for a `BroadcastReceiver` which in turn takes a wakelock and starts your `Service`.  The `Service` can then take its appropriate action and release the wakelock.  The system will ensure a wakelock is held long enough for your receiver's `onReceive()` method to complete.  It does not (and cannot) do the same for starting a `Service` or `Activity` from an alarm.

Comment: thanks, You mean i shouldn't start Service from Pending Intent, but start BroadcastReceiver and then start service from receiver?

Comment: Yes.  You'll also need to ensure the `BroadcastReceiver` takes a wakelock and the `Service` releases it when it is done doing whatever it does on wake up.  Otherwise there is a chance the system will go back to sleep before the `Service` ever gets to run.

Comment: I need to use PowerManager to ackqure wake lock?

Comment: Yes.  Alternatively, you can derive your receiver from `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` to help with this.  It wraps the calls to the `PowerManager` in order to make it easier to deal with.