# How to allow app to be used on without unlocking device screen?

Tags: android, screen-lock

How can I make my app usable when device is locked? Like when a timer/alarm goes off, I want it to be possible to access the entire app without unlocking the device.

Comment: If you combine a BroadcastReceiver and an AlarmManger, this should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you Taslim, that helped me, giving me something valuable search-terms.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048439/wake-phone-from-unlock-screen-android) where the question doesn't really make sense due to permissions, but the accepted answer is exactly what I was looking for. See linked question for details about below code.

```
    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

To implement an alarm see [Background jobs: AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/guide/background)